# Laravel: customize page links in pagination

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, pagination

I'm building an app with Laravel 5.5. and I need to customize the pagination. I have to apply css class on the page link elements. Where I find the template to override?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to launch this command from terminal:

`php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-pagination`

This creates the views in the `resources/views/vendor/pagination` directory.

Now you can apply your classes in the view: `default.blade.php`.

Read the documentation here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/pagination#customizing-the-pagination-view

Comment: Nothing to publish for tag [laravel-pagination].

Answer (score 7):

You can specify your own pagination view:

```
{{ $paginator->links('view.name') }}
```

From [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/pagination#customizing-the-pagination-view):

> By default, the views rendered to display the pagination links are compatible with the Bootstrap CSS framework. However, if you are not using Bootstrap, you are free to define your own views to render these links. When calling the links method on a paginator instance, pass the view name as the first argument to the method

Or you can customize the default view.

From [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/pagination#customizing-the-pagination-view):

> However, the easiest way to customize the pagination views is by exporting them to your `resources/views/vendor` directory using the `vendor:publish` command:
>
> `php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-pagination`
>
> This command will place the views in the `resources/views/vendor/pagination` directory. The `default.blade.php` file within this directory corresponds to the default pagination view. Edit this file to modify the pagination HTML.

Or, if you've just modified default Bootstrap classes, you can just load CSS after Bootstrap is loaded.

Answer (score 3):

You need to publish the views first with `php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-pagination` then they will appear in your `resources/views/vendor/pagination` folder and you can override them. Here is the [reference](http://php%20artisan%20vendor:publish%20--tag=laravel-pagination)

> This command will place the views in the `resources/views/vendor/pagination` directory. The **default.blade.php** file within this directory corresponds to the default pagination view. Simply edit this file to modify the pagination HTML.

Comment: You answered first tbh

Comment: Nothing to publish for tag [laravel-pagination].